# How can I make Google the default search provider instead of Bing?

Tags: google, bing, search

I was wondering if Google could be made the default search engine by pressing the 'Search' button rather than Bing. I'm not sure if Microsoft is okay with this.

Comment: This question now has [an actual answer](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/39/how-can-i-make-google-the-default-search-provider-instead-of-bing#3128)! Don't miss it ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Considering Bing is not just used for mere searching, but also integrates with the marketplace, and have support for places, vision, music and voice-search, replacing it with Google would require a large number of Google Services, and not just the search-engine.

Comment: I should add that no opinion on the relative merits of these search providers or information on Bing's services constitutes an attempt to answer this question.

Answer (score 9):

From a [Microsoft Answers post](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/winphone/forum/wp7-wpfeatures/windows-phone-7-ie-default-search-google/fbd8689b-d3d8-43f8-8b87-e9de841aad95):

> The default search engine is indeed set by the provider.  At the moment, there is no way for the end-user to override this default.  Many have asked for this feature, and I really hope we get it in a future update as the current behavior is anything but user-friendly.

So there doesn't seem to be an official way at the moment.

There is a [homebrew tool](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=931062) that could allow this, but you'd need a developer-unlocked phone, and it only seems to change the behavior of the button within IE, not system-wide.

Comment: That looks more like a user's response from the Microsoft Answers forum.

Comment: Indeed it is. Corrected my answer.

Comment: There is a workaround for the end-user to override the default (see my answer), so the comment you've quoted is not currently accurate.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to open Google from the the search button by changing your search language:

<kbd>SETTINGS</kbd> [image] <kbd>system</kbd> [image] <kbd>language+region</kbd> [image] <kbd>Browser & search language</kbd> [image] <kbd>Bashkir (Russia)</kbd>

Not all languages will work for this. I recommend Bashkir because it will make your phone open Google, but not make Google attempt to translate the results you find.

[image: search button] [image] [image]

---

If the above doesn't work, you may have to change another setting:

<kbd>SETTINGS</kbd> [image] <kbd>applications</kbd> [image] <kbd>Internet Explorer</kbd> [image] <kbd>advanced settings</kbd> [image] <kbd>Default search provider</kbd>

Change default search provider from Bing to Google.

Comment: +1 Worked for my Nokia Lumia 925 WP8, the search button used to open a bing search screen, after changing `browser and search language` to russian the search button now opens IE and directs to google. The language of google's site however, is controlled by cookies or location and therefor remained my language. Thanks!