# Bing search suggestion override

Tags: search, bing

When doing a Bing search (via the search hardware key or in IE's status bar) sometimes it replaces your search with a suggestion
`Were you looking for ... ?`
How do you ignore the suggestion and search for the original term?

Enclosing the original term in quotes is frustratingly ignored.

Comment: If you would rather have your search button take you to Google (where you can use quotation marks and selectively refuse suggested corrections), see [my answer to that question](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/39/how-can-i-make-google-the-default-search-provider-instead-of-bing#answer-3128).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there isn't a way :( Unlike the Google app you don't get a choice to search by the original terms.

Comment: Bing knows best... This implementation sucks!

Comment: That's the sting in using Bing! I don't find it an issue but then I do switch between using Bing and the Google app!